# How do I complete the Infected Farm?

Tags: wasteland-2, wasteland-2-directors-cut

On my way back to Ranger Citadel from the AG Center, I was told to go to the Infected Farm, so I did. I killed all the enemies, looted all the loot, and whispered all the cattle. The only object I seem to be able to interact with at this point is the water resevoir, seen below:

[image: resevoir]

But, whenever I try to Use it, the text panel just prints:

> Looks like you can pour fluid into the resevoir through the intake valve on its left side. From there it should get pumped throughout the entire area.

My only other option is to Examine, which prints:

> There's a small valve on the left side of this fertilizer resevoir.

There's no valve that I can find to interact with, which I think I confirmed by opening the skill wheel and it can only cycle through one object, the resevoir.

How do you complete this area? I can't tell if this is a bug, or if I'm missing an inventory item, or if I've done things in the wrong order. I saved Highpool, if that matters, but I just cleaned out the AG Center as well, which I believe is what triggered the Infected Farm being revealed on my map the next time I entered the wasteland.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am correct you should have a anti-serum in your inventory. (retrieved from lab). If you have done that I think the area is finished. more info [here](http://wasteland.wikia.com/wiki/Infected_Farm). If you want more details about if they are timed. there is a small [steam discussion](https://steamcommunity.com/app/240760/discussions/0/613937942908432665/) which adds some more info.

> all choices
>
> Reservoir
>
> ```
> Yes - use 1 dose Ag Center Serum - log book
> No
> ```

I wont post anything from the discussion as it is somewhat spoiler heavy